# LSTM predictions are one time step lagging

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

My problem involves electricity prediction (time-series problem) for 1-hour ahead. I am using LSTM to forecast.

- **Length of Dataset:** 1 year at one-hour interval
- **Input:** Outdoor Temperature (O<sub>t</sub>), Relative Humidty (RH<sub>t</sub>), historical electricity (E<sub>t</sub>)
- **Output:** Electricity (E<sub>t+1</sub>)

The `pearson correlation` between (E<sub>t</sub>) and (E<sub>t+1</sub>) is ~95%.  However, my forecast is lagging by 1-hour (one timestep) i.e. it is predicting E<sub>t</sub> at time (t+1).

**Network Architecture:**

```
epoch = 400
batch_size = 24
lr = 0.001

model = Sequential()

model.add((LSTM(units=20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(look_back, X_train.shape[2]), activation='relu')))
model.add((LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=True, activation='relu')))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 1,activation='sigmoid'))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=lr)
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = adam)

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch_size,verbose=1, shuffle = False)
model.summary()
```

**Model loss graph**

[image: Model Loss Graph]

**Predictions Graph**
[image: Predictions graphs]

The left-sided figure is the actual prediction where as the right-sided figure is one-hour shifted. As could be seen the actual predictions are one-hour lagging.

I have done hyper-parameter tuning as well using grid search.

Can anyone help me out on how to improve the performance? Is it because of the very low loss values ( in range of 1e<sup>-3</sup>) after 10-20 epochs and the incentive to learn is quite low?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you solved this lagging problem? I have the same problem with my LSTM networks.

Comment: @IgorPopov unfortunately no.Could you please let me know if you are able to solve this? Thanks

Comment: I found out on the Internet and in the book "Artificial intelligence in finance" by Yves Hilpisch that such approach for time series prediction is wrong. It is even possible to show mathematically. Fitting/optimization algorithms search for the closest fit that minimizes the loss for the given training set. When a same feature is both in X and Y (electricity in your case), the closest fit is E(t)=E(t-1). A solution is to transform X and/or Y to remove the simple/closest solution path in training.

Comment: @IgorPopov Do you happen to remember where in that book this is stated? I would like to learn more about this. Also, is there any recommendation on how to transform the training data?